# group concat a field based on 2 same data in another field

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, group-concat

Given this table,

```
+----+------------------+-----------+----------+
| id | Doctor name      | firsttime | lasttime |
+----+------------------+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Dr. Abdurahman   | 12:00:00  | 21:00:00 |
|  2 | Dr. Sultan Hamid | 12:00:00  | 21:00:00 |
|  3 | Dr. Susanti      | 12:00:00  | 21:00:00 |
|  4 | Dr. Siparman     | 12:00:00  | 21:00:00 |
|  5 | Dr. Ramah        | 12:00:00  | 21:00:00 |
|  6 | Drs. Susanto     | 13:00:00  | 22:00:00 |
|  7 | Dr. Budiarjo     | 13:00:00  | 22:00:00 |
|  8 | Dr. Antonius     | 13:00:00  | 22:00:00 |
|  9 | Dr. Wahid Bahyu  | 13:00:00  | 22:00:00 |
+----+------------------+-----------+----------+

expected
+----+--------------------------------------------+-----------+----------+
| id | Doctor name                                | firsttime | lasttime |
+----+--------------------------------------------+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Dr. Abdurahman, Dr. Sultan Hamid, etc      | 12:00:00  | 21:00:00 |
|  2 | Drs. Susanto, Dr. Budiarjo, etc            | 13:00:00  | 22:00:00 |
+----+--------------------------------------------+-----------+----------+
```

what i'm expecting is to select the table based on the first time and last time with group concat on Doctor name. So if there is the same firstdate AND lastdate it will be included in the group concat

Note: the first date and last date is random, ignore the etc, i want it full name of doctor

Comment: You are almost there, do GROUP_CONCAT in the select list, and GROUP BY firsttime, lasttime.

Comment: Do you need IDs in your result?

Comment: @juergend no, but if the sql needs it just show it

Comment: Do you want the "etc" or do you want the full list of doctors?

Comment: @GordonLinoff both, if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT firstdate,lastdate,
    GROUP_CONCAT(doctorname)
FROM
    table group by firstdate,lastdate
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use STRING_AGG() function:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(Doctor name, ', ') AS Doctor name, 
       firsttime, 
       lasttime 
FROM table 
GROUP BY firstdate, lastdate;
```